# Angular2, Drag events. Closure issue

Tags: javascript, angular, closures, drag

I'm building a directive for draggable components in Angular2. It has to work cross browsers, and here is where I have a problem. I learned that on FireFox, you cannot view the x,y coordinates for 'onDrag' mouse events. So I attached an event handler to the document so I can retrieve the coordinates using a 'dragover' function. However I think I have some problem with the closures of the event handlers.

On init, I attach the dragover handler for the entire document and store them in global temporary variables. However when I try accessing them 'onDrag' they still are at their original values.

Please can you help me solve the problem? or atleast understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDraggable]'
})
export class DraggableDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('appDraggable') data: any;

  private deltaX: number = 0;
  private deltaY: number = 0;

  private tempX: number = 0;
  private tempY: number = 0;

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //get the current element
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'draggable', 'true');

    //event listener to retrieve dragover coordinates.
    document.addEventListener("dragover", function (ev: DragEvent) {
      this.tempX = ev.x;
      this.tempY = ev.y;
    });
  }

  @HostListener('dragstart', ['$event'])
  onDragStart(e) {
    if (e.dataTransfer != null) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', null);
    }
    console.log("started dragging");

    this.deltaX = e.x - this._elementRef.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    this.deltaY = e.y - this._elementRef.nativeElement.offsetTop;
  }

  @HostListener('drag', ['$event'])
  onDrag(e) {
    console.log(this.tempX);
    this.setChanges(this._elementRef.nativeElement, this.renderer, this.tempX, this.tempY, this.deltaX, this.deltaY);
  }

  @HostListener('dragend', ['$event'])
  onDragEnd(e) {
    this.deltaX = 0;
    this.deltaY = 0;
    console.log('stopped dragging!');

    document.removeEventListener('dragover');
  }

  private setChanges(el: any, rend: Renderer, tempX: number, tempY: number, delX: number, delY: number) {
    if (!tempX || !tempY) return;

    rend.setElementStyle(el, 'top', (tempY - delY) + 'px');
    rend.setElementStyle(el, 'left', (tempX - delX) + 'px');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions `() => {` instead of `function () {` to retain the scope of `this`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //get the current element
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'draggable', 'true');

    //event listener to retrieve dragover coordinates.
    document.addEventListener("dragover", (ev: DragEvent) =>{
      this.tempX = ev.x;
      this.tempY = ev.y;
    });
  }
```